# echarts4r use valueFormatter in tooltip

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

I want to use the [`valueFormatter`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.valueFormatter) option in an echarts4r [tooltip](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/tooltip.html).
Following the [documentation of `e_tooltip`](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/reference/e-tooltip.html) I should be able to use the `...` args as they are passed to echarts.

For example I would expect this to work

```
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)

mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl, gear) |> 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) |>
  mutate(gear = as.character(gear)) |>
  e_charts(gear) |>
  e_bar(mpg) |>
  e_tooltip(
    trigger = "axis",
    valueFormatter = htmlwidgets::JS("(value) => 'MPG is ' + value.toFixed(2)")
  )
```

Leaving out the valueFormatter, I see this picture. The goal is to have the colored-dots in the tooltip and then on the RHS of the tooltip I want to see `MPG is 21.50` (Note that its fixed to 2 digits! aka showing the trailing 0), `MPG is 17.75` and `MPG is 15.05`.

[image: echarts]

Unfortunately, the tooltip does not work and crashes/shows nothing.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `value` passed to your formatter is a string. Hence, you have to first convert to a `Number` to apply the `toFixed` method:

```
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)

mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl, gear) |> 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) |>
  mutate(gear = as.character(gear)) |>
  e_charts(gear) |>
  e_bar(mpg) |>
  e_tooltip(
    trigger = "axis",
    valueFormatter = htmlwidgets::JS("(value) => 'MPG is ' + Number(value).toFixed(2)")
  )
```

[image]